# Shuffling and importing few rows of a saved numpy file

Tags: python, numpy, numpy-ndarray, numpy-memmap

I have 2 saved .npy files:

```
X_train - (18873, 224, 224, 3) - 21.2GB
Y_train - (18873,) - 148KB
```

X_train is cats and dogs images (cats being in 1st half and dogs in 2nd half, unshuffled) and is mapped with Y_train as 0 and 1. Thus Y_train is [1,1,1,1,1,1,.........,0,0,0,0,0,0].

**I want to import randomly say, 256 images  (both cats and dogs images in nearly 50-50%) in X and its mapping in Y. Since the data is large, I cannot import X_train in my RAM.**

Thus I have tried (1st approach):

```
import numpy as np
np.random.seed(666555)
X_train = np.load('Processed/X_train.npy', mmap_mode='r')
X = np.random.shuffle(X_train)
X = X[:256, :, :, :]
Y_train = np.load('Processed/Y_train.npy', mmap_mode='r')
Y = np.random.shuffle(Y_train)
Y = Y[:256]
```

This gives the following error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-68-8b2a13921b8d> in <module>
      2 np.random.seed(666555)
      3 X_train = np.load('Processed/X_train.npy', mmap_mode='r')
----> 4 X = np.random.shuffle(X_train)
      5 X = X[:256, :, :, :]
      6 Y_train = np.load('Processed/Y_train.npy', mmap_mode='r')

mtrand.pyx in numpy.random.mtrand.RandomState.shuffle()

mtrand.pyx in numpy.random.mtrand.RandomState.shuffle()

ValueError: assignment destination is read-only
```

I have also tried (2nd approach):

```
import numpy as np
np.random.seed(666555)
X = np.memmap('Processed/X_train.npy', 'float64', shape = (256, 224, 224, 3), mode = 'c')
Y = np.memmap('Processed/Y_train.npy', 'float64', shape = (256), mode = 'c')
X = np.random.shuffle(X)
Y = np.random.shuffle(Y)
print(X)
print(Y)
```

This outputs:

```
None
None
```

In 2nd approach, I will get only cats images as np.memmap will collect only 1st 256 images. Then shuffling will be of no use.

Please tell me how to do this with any method.

Comment: I think you want to pick a random list of 256 items from the mmap files.  I wouldn't try shuffling the files in-place.

Comment: Also, do you want to `random.shuffle` the arrays separately?  That will mix up the labeling!

Comment: Yes, I just want to randomly pick up 256 items from X_train in X and corresponding labels from Y_train in Y. Well, I got the solution from the below answer of @Marco Cerliani

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your shuffelling procedure is not correct. following this strategy you are also shuffling your X in a different way from Y (there is no more match between X and Y after shuffle). here a demonstrative example:

```
np.random.seed(666555)
xxx = np.asarray([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9])
yyy = np.asarray([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9])
np.random.shuffle(xxx)
np.random.shuffle(yyy)

print((yyy == xxx).all()) # False
```

here the correct procedure:

```
np.random.seed(666555)
xxx = np.asarray([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9])
yyy = np.asarray([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9])
idx = np.arange(0,len(xxx))
np.random.shuffle(idx)

print((yyy[idx] == xxx[idx]).all()) # True
```

in this way you also override the None problem